# IBOutlet with arc4random in swift3.0

Tags: swift3, iboutlet, arc4random

i have code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var detailText: String = "Chance of win is 50%"

@IBOutlet weak var winChance: UILabel!

func someMethod () -> Void {
    print("Method called!")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
self.winChance.text = self.detailText
}    }
```

how can i make arc4random for this 50%??
if i used something with "(var)" it is not help me
Thnx

Comment: you want label text to be `Chance of win is "randomnubmer"`?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var winChance: UILabel!

    func someMethod () -> Void {
        print("Method called!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        self.winChance.text = "Chance of win is \(randomNumber)%"
    }    
}
```